# ITK strange error after adding and compiling

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, itk

I just installed ITK for use on iOS and when I'm compiling it I get these weird errors.

When installing ITK i went through [this](http://www.sfu.ca/~zfh/IJ_755_1_BuildingITKinTheiPhone.pdf) document. All fine and ok at the end but then I strted working on the steps to actually show a DICOM image o screen, so I've used [this one](http://www.sfu.ca/~zfh/IJ_760_1_ITK_Image_IO_Interface_with_Apple_iOS.pdf). After adding 2 more header search paths to actually find the headers/classes I needed I get the following errors.

[image: errors_screenshot]

There are a lot more ... but I think you get the idea. I've tried googling about them but only found some other people having this problem on linux ... after changing compilers or something like that ... but I feel like that is a bit over my head right now so please help.

I'vre tried to change from LLVM to gcc but it didn't help, also tried Xcode version 3.something, 4 and 4.2 and no luck yet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you add the ITK library to your project? The header search paths are not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You're clearly still missing headers.  I'd guess your search paths are not correct or you added them to the wrong build setting.  For example, if the paths are system-style paths (#include <header>) they should go in the Header Search Paths setting.  However if they're user-style paths (#include "header.h") they should go in the User Header Search Paths setting.